# Extract domain name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following rows:

```
http://domain1.com/moshe
https://domain2.com/
https://domain3.com
https://domain4.com?gembom
```

I need these results

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
```

How exactly can I do it in MySQL?

In JavaScript, I can simply use regex:

```
string.match(/https?:\/\/([^/]+)/)[0]
```

But I found, that MySQL doesn't have extracting regex. Is there an alternative way to achieve the same results?

Comment: What is the purpose of the extraction? It'd be a rather heavy operation to do in a "real time" search so may be better to do elsewhere.

Comment: Purpose: `Grouping by domain. select afuncton(url) as domain, count(*) group by domain.`

Comment: The ideal way would be to do this on the application level, most platforms have a proper URL parsing function/method/library. Remember special cases, like  `http://pekka.rocks` is a valid domain name now. Also consider port numbers: `http://pekka.rocks:8080` etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to extract the domain names from urls in MySQL,

```
DECLARE @WebUrl VARCHAR(35);
SET @WebUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=trim'

SELECT @WebUrl AS 'WebsiteURL',
       LEFT(SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, 
       (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//',@WebUrl)=0 
            THEN 5 
            ELSE  CHARINDEX('//',@WebUrl) + 2
            END), 35),
       (CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, CHARINDEX('//', @WebUrl) + 2, 35))=0 
       THEN LEN(@WebUrl) 
       else CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, CHARINDEX('//', @WebUrl) + 2, 35))- 1
       END)
       ) AS 'Domain

';
```

You can make suitable modifications to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, But how do I use it in `select` query that return also another column. for example: `select id,url, *domain* from table?`
I want to add a column to the results. Not just parse it.

Comment: Not compatible with MariaDB. Fatal error: 1305 - FUNCTION CHARINDEX does not exist.